# mysql, json data type, efficient query at scale

Tags: mysql, json

I'm making a simple social media app. I'm storing all comments and likes that relate to a post in a json field type so that I only need to perform a single lookup to grab them (my database is relational, otherwise).

I'm thinking ahead to a "Newsfeed" page load time, where it grabs 25 posts at a time. If in the future, if a particular post had hundreds or thousands of comments, with some of those comments being fairly long, that could be a lot of data to grab from the database, especially if there were several of those kinds of posts.

So essentially, The at most bare bones I need to know on first load is the total # of likes, total # of comments, one user who liked it, and one user who commented. The rest I can query on with ajax calls later if they want more.

My field (post_interactions) that stores the json data looks like this:

```
{"likes": ["bob", "james"], "comments": ["one", "two", "three"]}
```

How I'm thinking I want to do the query:

```
SELECT
    user,
    id,
    created_at,
    post_interactions->"$.likes[0]",
    post_interactions->"$.comments[0]",
    JSON_LENGTH(post_interactions->"$.likes") AS LikeCount,
    JSON_LENGTH(post_interactions->"$.comments") AS CommentCount
FROM user_posts
WHERE id = "id"
```

I want to know if this query is something that would be efficient at scale, or if there's a better way to approach this (the fact that I'm using the json field type is set, just a better way to approach it given that fact).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _"the fact that I'm using the json field type is set"_ - well then there isn’t much help possible.

Comment: Don't use the JSON type in MySQL the JSON parsing functions are pretty bad in MySQL, Postgresql has much beter JSON support.. you better can create two more tables thats hold likes and comments..

Comment: @raymondNijland maybe you could support that postgresql comment a bit? The beauty  of using a nosql approach for this is you only need a single lookup. In my case, I am only doing this for 25 rows at a time. Further, I can query for and cache the next result set before it's called. The experience will not be slow. Now, at scale, if I needed to grab thousands or tens of thousands of rows I was returning in a single query, and I was aggregating json data for all of them, MySQL would lose big time against other nosql approaches (Mongo, etc). Using indexed virtual columns puts them on par.